Problem when trying to mix a Jetty-12 ee8 Servlet and Jetty Handler s
I am trying to migrate my application using an embedded jetty 10 (10.0.20) to jetty 12 (12.0.14) and I would like to migrate all I can to the Jetty Handler paradigm.
Yet, my application uses the ImageServlet of JasperReports 6 which relies on Servlet 4.0.
Server httpServer = ...

ContextHandler adminContextHandler = new ContextHandler("/admin");
// add the SessionHandler in first place
SessionHandler sessionHandler = new SessionHandler();
adminContextHandler.setHandler(sessionHandler);
Handler.Sequence adminHandlers = new Handler.Sequence();
sessionHandler.setHandler(adminHandlers);
// the regular adminHandler with the Jetty Handler paradigm
PathMappingsHandler adminHandler = new PathMappingsHandler();
...
// add the adminHandler to the sequence
adminHandlers.addHandler(adminHandler);

// the ee8 Servlet for JasperReports which supports Servlet 4.0
// the ImageServlet is a built-in servlet of JasperReport used to get the images from a Html report.
// since ee8 ServletContextHandler seems to not extend ContextHandler, 
// I use the addHandler(Supplier<Handler>) method of the Handler.Collection
ServletContextHandler jasperServletContextHandler = new ServletContextHandler();
jasperServletContextHandler.addServlet(ImageServlet.class, "/reports/image");
// add the ServletContextHandler to the Sequence
adminHandlers.addHandler(jasperServletContextHandler);
...
// the collection holding every contexts
ContextHandlerCollection contextCollection = new ContextHandlerCollection(adminContextHandler, ...);
httpServer.setHandler(contextCollection);

When I am trying to make a report, which leads to download an image from the the ImageServlet, I get this Error :
HTTP ERROR 404 Not Found
URI: /admin/reports/image
STATUS: 404
MESSAGE: Not Found
SERVLET: org.eclipse.jetty.ee8.servlet.ServletHandler$Default404Servlet-7c8326a4
I am then not sure that I am using the mix Jetty Handler paradigm and Jetty Servlet EE8 properly. Is it okay to add a ee8 ServletContextHandler into a Handler.Sequence like I did ? It seems to me that with my structure, the ImageServlet is never invoked.
BTW, I was not able to find the source code for the ee8 packages on the jetty-project github.
Thanks for your help.
